# Load csv files from different different directories using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataset in csv files, the files are in two directories A and B, they have two subdirectories Time and Error. Time has a file named task_time.csv and Error has a file named task_error.csv

The csv files are in a single column, I have to split them into 3 columns to perform my analysis.

I want to figure out the logic to load these files into a dataframe that could be used for data analysis like finding the mean for a particular file like task_time.csv

I am not able to load the data files that are structured in this way to work on the data analysis. Any help to figure it out will be appreciated

Comment: can you provide sample data of each file? what are using to split each file into three columns if they are only one column?

Comment: Users Task1 Task2 Task3                                                                                                    0     3005 3489 3610
 1     3010 3526 3608
 2     2980 3480 3599
 3     3011 3489 3602
 4     2998 3488 3583                                                                                                 This is how it looks like, I am using split method by pandas

Comment: you're going to need to edit your question and put the data in there and explain in more deatil what it is. that doesn't necessarily look like one column from a csv file, but maybe it is???